# Static instance variables in python

Tags: python

I am trying to learn about static variables in python. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python/#answer-27568860) answer this piece of code should make `i` unique for all the objects of class `Test`

The code:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     _i = 3
...     @property
...     def i(self):
...             return self._i
...     @i.setter
...     def i(self,val):
...             self._i = val
... 
>>> 
>>> x1 =  Test()
>>> x1.i
3
>>> x2 = Test()
>>> x2.i
3
>>> x1.i = 10
>>> x1.i
10
>>> x2.i
3
```

But as you can see object x1.i is not equal to x2.i.
I tried to do this in both python 2.7 and 3.4 but the result is same.
I think my understanding about this concept is wrong.

Could somebody please explain this to me or guide me to a resource.

Comment: They are unique as you expected in your second sentence. What exactly is your question?

Comment: That linked answer has it wrong. `self._i = val` will assign to a local to that instance attribute *_i* (which then shadows the class attr), not the class attribute.

Comment: You should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/69067/4642859)

Comment: @Selcuk in the linked answer it mentions that `x1.i` is equal to `x2.i`, which does not happen when I tried to do the same. my question is if I am wrong or the mentioned answer is misleading.

Comment: @IljaEverilä That's what confused me. Thanks.

Comment: "I am trying to learn about static variables in python" : well, Python has no such thing, period.  If what you're talking about is "an attribute that is shared by all instances of the class", the correct term is "class attribute" - which is really an instance attribute of the class object (Python's classes are objects too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python/#answer-27568860) gets it wrong.

```
class Test(object):
    i = 0


t = Test()
t.i = 4
print t.i
>>> 4
print t.__class__.i
>>> 0
```

Fields declared on the `class` are looked up when not found on the instance, but you cannot modify the class directly via `self`. `self.i = 4` always  modifies the instance. You can do stuff like

```
class Test(object):
    _i = 0

    @property
    def i(self):
        return self._i

    @i.setter
    def i(self, value):
        Test._i = value
```

But duplicating the class name all over the place does not seem a good idea and  `self.__class__` does not play too well with inheritance. This also completely hides the fact that `i` was initially a class variable which may or may not be a good idea, either.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Fields declared on the class are copied to self's dictionary", but it doesn't sound right. `i` is not in the instance dict until you set it explicitly on `t`; rather, when Python resolves the name it falls back to the class-level attribute if it is not found at instance level.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hmm. It seems I fell for `dir()`'s magic, here (it shows `i`). Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test(object):

    _i = 3

    @property
    def i(self):
        return self._i

    @i.setter
    def i(self,val):
        self._i = val

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x1 =  Test()
    x2 = Test()

    x1.i = 10
    print(x1.__dict__)
    print(Test.__dict__)

{'_i': 10}
{'i': <property object at 0x02551180>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Test' objects>, '_i': 3, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Test' objects>}
```

x1.i = 10 create values object